# [[ -v var ]] behaves differently inside bash script vs CLI

Tags: command-line, bash, debian, bash-scripting

I want a bash script that will set several environment variables (userid, password, token) to some default values if they don't already exist.  The existence test works on the CLI but not in the script.

```
magilla@raspberrypi:~ $ ps -p $$
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
   3005 pts/0    00:00:05 bash
magilla@raspberrypi:~ $ echo "${BASH_VERSION}"
5.1.4(1)-release

magilla@raspberrypi:~ $ env | grep var
magilla@raspberrypi:~ $ [[ -v var ]] && echo "\${var} not defined" || echo "\${var} is defined"
${var} not defined

magilla@raspberrypi:~ $ cat myscript
#!/bin/bash
[[ -v var ]] && echo "\${var} not defined" || echo "\${var} is defined"
magilla@raspberrypi:~ $ bash myscript
${var} is defined
magilla@raspberrypi:~ $ bash < myscript
${var} is defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `var` is set in your interactive shell (it's not in the environment though). Then `[[ -v var ]]` returns success and `echo "\${var} not defined"` is executed.

You see `not defined` because the logic of your code is wrong.

In the script `var` is not set, `[[ -v var ]]` returns failure and `echo "\${var} is defined"` is executed.

You see `is defined` because again the logic is wrong. The following logic makes sense:

```
[[ -v var ]] && echo "\${var} is defined" || echo "\${var} not defined"
```

It's opposite to the logic of your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  For what it's worth I got this code from this [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/see-check-if-bash-variable-defined-in-script-on-linux-unix-macos/).  I see that the logic is reversed.  The `env | grep` checked the environment.  How do I check that `var` is set in the interactive shell?

Comment: Also, I read elsewhere that passing `${var}` rather than `var` to -v would not be right, as it would expand that possibly-unset variable before the test operator sees it; so it has to be part of that operator's task to inspect that variable, pointed to by its name, and tell whether it is set.  In short, -z tests a value and –v tests a name.  The link shows `${var}` so perhaps there are 2 things wrong over there?

Comment: `set` with no arguments prints out all the env vars, shell vars and functions.